# Speeding up "Old" string parsing methods using PLINQ or Async/Await or TPL, etc

Tags: vb.net, parsing, asynchronous, parallel-processing, plinq

As (hopefully) all developers, I've developed over the years and am now at the point that OOP and functional programming is a daily costs. Recently I've bumped into and "old" (2 years) DLL of my that reads in a TCP stream, drops the incoming string (which end with a line feed) into a ConcurrentQueue(Of String). Then a second Backgroundworker loops over the ConcurrentQueue(Of String) and dequeue's the string and parses it.

Depending on the request command I send to the TCP server I get one line or several hundreds of lines. Also when nothing is asked the TCP server sends nothing. It is completely event driven.

With the new and efficient Technics of PLINQ, Async/Await and TPL I am determine to make this faster/more efficient. Currently I'm brainstorming on how to do this and am asking you to think with me or give some good advice.

So let's dig deeper into what I have now:
It al starts with two Backgroundworkers, One for Reading and One for Parsing.

The Reading Backgroundworker:
This backgroundworker job is to read the incoming data and make sure to keep reading until a Linefeed is passed. Then it cuts into a string and drops it into a ConcurrentQueue(Of String). The code looks like this:

```
Private Sub bgwReceive_DoWork(sender As Object, e As DoWorkEventArgs) Handles bgwTCP_Receive.DoWork

    Dim strRXData As String = String.Empty
    Dim intLfpos As Integer = 0

    Try
        Do Until bgwTCP_Receive.CancellationPending

            'while the client is connected, continue to wait for and read data
            While _Client.Connected AndAlso _ClientStream.CanRead
                Dim buffer(_Client.ReceiveBufferSize - 1) As Byte
                Dim read As Integer = _ClientStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)

                'Put the new data in the queue
                If read > 0 Then

                    'Add incomming data to the buffer string
                    strRXData &= Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, read)

                    'Replace "0 padding"
                    strRXData.Replace(Chr(0), String.Empty)

                    'Now check if we have a Linefeed in our buffer string
                    While strRXData <> String.Empty

                        'Get the position of the first linefeed
                        intLfpos = strRXData.IndexOf(vbLf)

                        'Now check if we find something.
                        If intLfpos < 0 Then Exit While

                        'There is a line feed, it is time to add it to the incoming data queue
                        IncommingData.Enqueue(strRXData.Substring(0, intLfpos - 1))

                        'Now remove the command from the buffer string
                        strRXData = strRXData.Substring(intLfpos + 1, strRXData.Length - intLfpos - 1)

                    End While
                End If

                'Check if we have to stop
                If bgwTCP_Receive.CancellationPending Then e.Cancel = True : Exit Do

                Threading.Thread.Sleep(1)
            End While

            Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)
        Loop

        e.Cancel = True

    Catch op As OperationCanceledException
        Throw New Exception("TCP Reading cancelled")
    Catch se As SocketException
        Throw New Exception("Socket unknown error. Native error code: " & se.NativeErrorCode)
    Catch IOex As IOException
        Throw New Exception("Socket timeout while receiving data from [" & TCP_ServerIP.ToString & "]")
    End Try
End Sub
```

The Parsing Backgroundworker: This backgroundworker job is to parse the strings in the ConcurrentQueue(Of String). In this backgroundworker there is a big Select case that looks at the first word in the string. This determines what to do.

The received protocol is very simple but unfortunately it hasn't a solid structure like JSON. A string would look like this: IND PARM1:"Hello world!" PARM2:1.4.8 \CrLf

As you can see it is very simple and plain. The IND indicate the Command, like VER is for VERSION string. IND is always 3 chars long. Then comes the parameters. The parameter name is always 4 chars long. If it is between double quotes it is a string, else its something like a double/integer/IP address (X.X.X.X). Keep in mind that original it is a string. In my parser I parse it to the object properties. The code looks like this:

```
Private Sub bgwProcessQueue_DoWork(sender As Object, e As DoWorkEventArgs) Handles bgwProcessQueue.DoWork

    Dim strNewLine As String = String.Empty
    Dim strSubLine As String = String.Empty

    Try
        'Loop until program has stopped
        Do Until bgwProcessQueue.CancellationPending

            'Only process when something is in the queue
            If TCP_Connection.IncommingData.TryDequeue(strNewLine) Then

                'If Backgroundworker has to cancel than cancel
                If bgwProcessQueue.CancellationPending Then Exit Do

                Select Case True

                    Case strNewLine.StartsWith("VER") 'Example:     VER PRM1:1.1 PRM2:"Hi there" PRM3:1.1.1 PRM4:8/0 PRM5:8

                        'First check if all the needed values are there, if not resend the command
                        If strNewLine.Contains("PRM1:") AndAlso strNewLine.Contains("PRM2:") AndAlso strNewLine.Contains("PRM3:") AndAlso strNewLine.Contains("PRM4:") AndAlso strNewLine.Contains("PRM5:") Then

                            'Get versions and devicename
                            Me.Param1 = GetSubstring(strNewLine, "PRM1:", " ")
                            Me.Param2 = GetSubstring(strNewLine, "PRM2:", " ")
                            Me.Param3 = GetSubstring(strNewLine, "PRM3:", " ")
                            Me.Param4 = GetSubstring(strNewLine, "PRM4:", " ")
                            Me.Param5 = GetSubstring(strNewLine, "PRM5:", " ")
                        
                        Else
                            'Commando was invalid, resend the command
                            Log.Message(LogLevel.Warning, "VER Messages was incompleet, resending VER command")
                            SendData("VER")
                        End If

                    Case strNewLine.StartsWith("ERROR")
                        Log.Message(LogLevel.Warning, strNewLine)
                End Select
            End If

            'Clear any old data
            strNewLine = String.Empty

            'Sleep
            Threading.Thread.Sleep(1)
        Loop

        e.Cancel = True
    Catch ex As Exception
        Log.Exception(ex)
    End Try
End Sub

Private Function GetSubstring(text As String, StartValue As String, EndValue As String) As String

    Try
        'If we can't find the Start value we can't do anything
        If Not text.Contains(StartValue) Then Return String.Empty

        'Find the index of the Start and End value
        intStartValueIndex = text.IndexOf(StartValue) + StartValue.Length
        intEndValueIndex = text.IndexOf(EndValue, intStartValueIndex)

        'If no Endvalue index was found then get the end of the string
        If intEndValueIndex < intStartValueIndex Then intEndValueIndex = text.Length

        'Return the substring en remove quetes
        Return text.Substring(intStartValueIndex, intEndValueIndex - intStartValueIndex).Replace("""", "")
    Catch ex As Exception
        Log.Exception(ex)
        Return String.Empty
    End Try
End Function
```

Hopefully all above is understandable. I was thinking of looping through the ConcurrentQueue(Of String) with a Parrallel.ForEach Which passes the Dequeued string into a sub that does the parsing. At the reading side, my inspiration is empty at the moment...

Comment: Do you actually have a performance problem?  Have you used a profiler to determine where the bottleneck is?

Comment: Not that i know off. Just want to learn how things could be Made with New insights.